# Full width alert dialog buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

I'm trying to get my `AlertDialogs` to look like this, with the full width button:

[image]

I'm following the Google's [documentation](https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#using-dialogs) and it says to use this style:

```
 R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog_FullWidthButtons
```

but I don't have access to that theme:

[image]

I have the appropriate dependency added in the project's Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

I feel like I'm just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of the theme overlays is missing in the library.
You can define it on your own, by:

Declare a full width button style, like:

```
  <style name="Button.FullWidth" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">@null</item>
  </style>
```

Declare the theme overlay with full-width button styles:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog.FullWidthButtons">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogButtonSpacerVisibility">2</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Button.FullWidth</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Button.FullWidth</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/Button.FullWidth</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: This works pretty good but do you know how to get full width buttons if you inherit from "Theme.Material3.Dark.Dialog.Alert"?

Comment: I found if you set `android:layout_weight` to something like 10, it works but that doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel's Answer is pretty good. If you want to remove the middle space just set

```
<item name="materialAlertDialogButtonSpacerVisibility">2</item>
```

in your alert dialog style that means `GONE`. The default value is `1` that means `invisible`.

Comment: Yeah but it begs the question why the style isn't in the library.

Comment: I know, I just answered your question you have aske in the comment to Gabriel's answer.

Comment: It's more of a rhetorical question since only Google can answer it.